# Pandas dataframe sum in categories

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which looksl ike this:

```
import pandas as pd

ticker = ['YAR.OL', 'DNB.OL', 'TSLA', 'NHY.OL', 'SBO.OL', 'STB.OL']
country = ['Norway', 'Norway', 'United States', 'Norway', 'Norway', 'Norway']
alloc = [11.822, 2.917, 0.355, 74.158, 9.673, 1.075]

dfn = pd.DataFrame(country,columns =['country'])
dfn['Allocation'] = pd.DataFrame(alloc)
```

[image]

I would like to sum the allocation of every country, for instance:
Norway: 99,645
United States: 0,355

How can I do this in python using the df i have generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add one line code at end

```
dfn=dfn.groupby(['country']).sum()
```

at a glance

```
import pandas as pd

ticker = ['YAR.OL', 'DNB.OL', 'TSLA', 'NHY.OL', 'SBO.OL', 'STB.OL']
country = ['Norway', 'Norway', 'United States', 'Norway', 'Norway', 'Norway']
alloc = [11.822, 2.917, 0.355, 74.158, 9.673, 1.075]

dfn = pd.DataFrame(country,columns =['country'])
dfn['Allocation'] = pd.DataFrame(alloc)
dfn=dfn.groupby(['country']).sum()

print(dfn)
```

output:

```
country           Allocation               
Norway             99.645
United States       0.355
```

Answer (score 2):

at first, you must use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` function. [see explanations here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).
by `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` you can do whatever you want in a group of names. like `mean()` and in your case `sum()`.

```
>>> dfn2 = dfn.groupby(['country'])
>>> dfn2.sum()

country        Allocation          
Norway             99.645
United States       0.355
```

you can do this in a single line too.

```
>>> dfn.groupby(['country']).sum()

country        Allocation
Norway             99.645
United States       0.355
```